# c# get non-working days in a month based on a shift

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I have a List of days (working days) in an employee shift like below:

```
List<int> workingDays = new List<int>();
workingDays.Add(1); // monday
workingDays.Add(2); // tuesday
workingDays.Add(3); // wednesday
workingDays.Add(5); // friday
```

Those are the working days for an employee.

Now, I need to get all the days in a selected month where is a non-working day.

For example:

If July has 31 days I should get the following list:

```
July 3 // thursday is a non-working day
July 5 // saturday is a non-working day
July 6 // sunday is a nono-working day
July 10 // thursday is a non-working day
```

And so on...

Any clue on how to get that list?

UPDATE:

This is my attempt:

```
for (int day = 1; day <= DateTime.DaysInMonth(currentDate.Year, currentDate.Month); day++) {
    DateTime dt = new DateTime(currentDate.Year, currentDate.Month, day);
    var shiftDay = shifts.Where(s => (int) dt.DayOfWeek - 1 == s.Day && s.IsActive).First();

    if (shiftDay == null) {

        // this is a non-working day because wasn't found in the shift List

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `DayOfWeek` enumeration instead of int to make your code more readable and less prone to errors:

```
List<DayOfWeek> workingDays = new List<DayOfWeek>() { 
    DayOfWeek.Monday, DayOfWeek.Tuesday, DayOfWeek.Wednesday, DayOfWeek.Friday
};


var nonWorkingDays = Enumerable.Range(1, 31)
                               .Select(x => new DateTime(2014, 7, x))
                               .Where(d => !workingDays.Contains(d.DayOfWeek))
                               .ToList();
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it with Int values isntead of DayOfWeek enums?

Comment: You can cast `int` and `DayOfWeek` to each other. You should be able to figure out how to make it work for `int`s.